# Kendo UI: Localization of the grid through asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there any way to set up new message for the Kendo UI Grid from a ASP.NET MVC code ? I'm stuck with a Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.FilterableMessagesBuilder object that I need to pass to the messages method. 
So what should I pass in the Messages method to change the value ?

```
@(

Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(col =>
    {
        col.Bound(p => p.Id);
        col.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
        col.Bound(p => p.LastName);
        col.Bound(p => p.Address);
        col.Bound(p => p.Zip);
    })

    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable(filter => filter.Messages(Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.FilterableMessagesBuilder
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     .Filterable(filterable => filterable.Messages(messages =>
         {
             messages.Info("Custom header text"); // sets the text on top of the filter menu
             messages.Filter("CustomFilter"); // sets the text for the "Filter" button
             messages.Clear("CustomClear"); // sets the text for the "Clear" button
         }))
```

Please look at Kendo Documentation (search for Localization of the filter menu)

[Localization of the filter menu](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/grid/localization)

Comment: Thanks, I've looked the documentation but there is no example for ASP.NET cshtml coding style.